# "ten more percent" or "ten percent more" in a sentence

Tags: comparative-constructions

He is determined to get _______ of the profit than he has been offered.

Should I put "ten percent more" or "ten more percent" in the blank? Or, either is fine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Units of measurement can sometimes be placed differently, for example:

- Five more miles
- Five miles more

But a percentage is **not** a unit of measurement. A percentage is really a fraction where the denominator is fixed at 100. It is not used the same way as a unit of measurement.

In your example, "*ten percent more of the profit*" is correct.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and explanation. But I have done some research on Google and found sentences like 

"In a Gallup Poll taken between July 11 and July 14, Trump's received 38 percent approval and 57 percent disapproval rating. These numbers show him getting {one more percent} than last week poll that showed him with 37 percent."

Source: https://www.ibtimes.com/trump-approval-remains-steady-conservatives-grow-frustrated-russian-scandal-2566232

Comment: @ChaoZHANG Yes, but in your example, you were proposing to use it like a unit of measurement. In the example you have found online they are *comparing* two percentages. Think about it - if you had a cohort of 50 and you received 1 percent more, that would be 0.5. You're not receiving 'one' of something. But when you're comparing percentages then it's like-for-like, it can be acceptable to say "one more", although personally I'd avoid it.

Comment: What if the author does want to describe an increase of 10% in the absolute sense? Say the revenue is USD 1000, with USD 900 in cost and USD 100 in total profit.

"He" has been offered USD 50, 50% of the profit.

"He" now wants USD 60, where his cut increases from 50% to 60% of the total profit.

What's the most natural way to specify a 10% increase in such {absolute sense}? 10 percent more can be ambiguous here?

Comment: @ChaoZHANG You make a good point here. "Ten percent more" is not ambiguous in the example you give. But I know what you mean. Where, for example an entity makes a return on investment of 10% in yr one, and 20% in year two - they do NOT make a 100% increase in ROI. as some managers I have known might have suggested. In a case like that you may be justified in saying "ten more percent". But I would say "ten percentage points more". Newspaper headline writers are the worst culprits when it comes to expressing opinion-poll results for political parties, in this regard.

Comment: @ChaoZHANG My children have grown up with devices like phones and tablets where the battery charge is represented as a percentage. I've heard them say things like "I need more percent!" which is laughably incorrect to an adult. As a native speaker to an English learner I would advise to use percentage carefully. This ngram demonstrates that your suggestion is not found in Google books: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ten+percent+more%2Cten+more+percent&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @Astralbee Thank you very much for citing the Google Books Ngram viewer. Indeed, "ten more percent" is not found in there. However, "10 more percent" has been found in extremely rare cases, while "one more percent" is actually a lot more common. I really appreciate your inputs both from the linguistic and the research perspective. Super helpful. I can now sleep in peace knowing "ten percent more" is the much more natural and common usage in such cases. Many thanks!!!

Comment: @WS2 Thanks for getting right to the point where it confuses me the most. It does sound more natural to say "ten percentage points more" for the context I created. Much appreciated!!! Percentages can be really tricky for non-native speakers like me.